# Change Text of a Modal Dynamically Using JavaScript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a custom modal which I am implementing into a project. I want the modal to be reusable and allow multiple buttons in the project to utilize the same modal but just change the text and elements within the modal dynamically. Right now I am able to open the same modal with 2 separate button clicks. I am now stuck and can't figure out how to update the innerHTML or innerText of the modal depending on which button is clicked.

modal.js

```
/*
* Apply the .modal-toggle class to any button to open the same modal
* */

let modal = document.querySelector('.custom-modal-bg');
let modalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-toggle');
let numOfModalButtons = modalButtons.length;
let changeeText = document.querySelector('.change-text');


function attachModalListeners(modalElm) {
    modalElm.querySelector('#cancel').addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
    modalElm.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', toggleModal);
}

function toggleModal(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    let currentModalState = modal.classList.contains('modal-active');

    if (!currentModalState) {
        modal.classList.add('modal-active')
        currentModalState = true;
    } else {
        modal.classList.remove('modal-active')
    }
}

//Allow multiple buttons to open modal
for (let i = 0; i < numOfModalButtons; i++) {
    modalButtons[i].addEventListener('click', toggleModal, false);
}
```

My Html modal mark up

```
<!--Modal div-->
<div class="custom-modal-bg">
    <div class="custom-modal">
        <h5 class="subtitle">Add new Label</h5>
        <label for="newModalLabel">Label Name:</label>
        <input
                class="input is-small"
                type="text"
                name="newModalLabel"
                id="newModalLabel"
                placeholder="Type a new label name">
        <div>
            <button id="add" type="submit" class="button is-small">Add
                Label
            </button>
            <button id="cancel" class="button is-dark is-small">Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--END Modal div-->
```

Button One utilizing modal

```
<div class="label-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a
                    href="javascript:;"
                    class="modal-toggle"
                    id="newLabel"
                    data-blog="<?php echo $blog->blogID;?>"
            >
                New label...
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php $dashObj->getLabelsMenu($blog->blogID) ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

2nd Element utilizing modal

```
<button
        class="modal-toggle change-title"
        id="publishBtn"
>
    Publish
</button>
```

Comment: Maybe add `data-` attributes to the buttons with the text you want in the modal and then update `toggleModal` to make the changes before opening the modal.

Comment: @Ouroborus would it be possible for you to provide an example? Thank you.